# How can I disable all the ui buttons in the main menu?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This method is being called from a UI canvas button in the editor.
The problem is when I click on the continue button while it's loading the game because it's fading out slowly I can still click on other buttons like a new game or continue or settings.

When I clicked on the continue button, I want the buttons to click on them not to make now be shown but not to click on them.

```
public void ContinueGameButton()
    {
        transform.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        LoadSceneForSavedGame = true;
        newGameDialog.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine(sceneFader.FadeAndLoadScene(SceneFader.FadeDirection.In, _newGameButtonLevel));
    }
```

This screenshot shows the UI buttons I have 3 groups because each time depending on if it's a new game or if there is a saved game then show a different menu.

This is the group that is enabled when there is a saved game :

[image: main menu]

And now when I click the Continue Game UI Btn I want to disable from clicking the :

New Game UI Btn
Continue UI Btn
Options UI Btn
Exit UI Btn

The script with the ContinueGameButton() method is attached to the UIController :

[image: main menu controller]

This is a link for the full script with the ContinueGameButton() method at lines 267 to 273 :

https://pastebin.com/qZ8ss8PV

This is how the main menu looks like when the game is running and when I click the Continue button I want that there will be no way to click on the Continue button again or any other buttons :

[image: Main menu when the game is running]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general in order to disable all the `UI.Button` components under a certain `GameObject` simply do e.g.

```
foreach (var btn in rootObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>(true))
{
    btn.interactable = false;
}
```

See

- [`GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html)
- [`Button.interactable`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-interactable.html)

Don't forget to enable them again later ;)